# When to use find over logical indexing

Tags: matlab, optimization, indexing, find

I need to return the first value in an array that is greater than another particular value.  I have:

```
find(A > val, 1, 'first')
```

According to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9464886/1985603 find is unavoidable in this case. But, what about:

```
B = A(A > val);
B(1)
```

Is there a good reason to use one over the other here, other than the extra line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is; speed! Especially for large arrays, `find` will be significantly faster.

Think about it: the operation `A > val` is the same in both cases, but

```
B = A(A > val)
```

extracts values from `A`, and copies them into a new array `B`, which will have to be allocated and copy-assigned, and the `A(A> val)` temporary will have to be destroyed.

All `find(A>val, 1, 'first')` does is walk the list of logicals, and return a single number when it encounters the first `true` value; this is a lot less useless copying/assigning/etc., and therefore, much faster.

As a rule of thumb, when you don't use the additional options in `find`, logical indexing is almost always preferable. When you need or use `find`'s additional functionalities, the `find` option is almost always preferable.

Comment: Thanks!  That was exactly the answer I was looking for :-)