# The Fastest Way for Logical Operation (e.g. Less than <) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, performance, logical-operators, bigdata

Assume, there is a massive data set like:

```
    A = 10^8 * rand( 10^8 , 1 ) ;
```

Then, what is the fastest way of selecting members of `A` that are less than `X` (e.g. 4000.23) in MATLAB:

```
    X = 4000.23 ;
    B =  A ( A < X) ;
```

Please let me know if there is any faster way of finding `B`. Thanks

Comment: Another way, but probably slower: `B = find(A < X)`. Try it with `tic` and `toc` yourself. Simply run it within a loop 1000 times and measure the time with tic/toc for various ways of doing

Comment: I used 'find'. But, it's still not faster. Thanks though

Comment: That's the fastest way you're ever going to get it. The reason why it's slow is because the size of your data is huge. You **may** achieve faster times if your dataset is predominantly sparse, so you can use `sparse` to create the matrix. Otherwise, this is as fast as you're going to get it. Sorry!

Comment: @tim `find` can be preferred over `logical` indexing if you don't want to return **all** of the values that match a certain condition.  `find` has options to find the first `N` or last `N` values that satisfy the condition in the array.  This would obviously be much faster than to use logical indexing where you'd have to copy over an array that meets the criteria you're looking for, and then you index into it. As a general rule, if you want to return **all** values, use `logical` indexing. This may give insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491520/when-to-use-find-over-logical-indexing

Comment: Or maybe try to code it in C. But as @rayryeng stated, you are already doing it the fastest way.